# VB.NET Combobox is showing the record name but no data?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, combobox, datatable

It is a little complicated to explain. So allow me to explain with a few pictures below. First of all, I bind my combobox to my datatable such as

```
   Try
        Using myConn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            myCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM product_list", myConn)
            productDT = New DataTable()
            productDA = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
            Dim myCB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(productDA)
            productDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
            productDA.InsertCommand = myCB.GetInsertCommand
            productDA.UpdateCommand = myCB.GetUpdateCommand
            productDA.DeleteCommand = myCB.GetDeleteCommand

            productDA.Fill(productDT)
        End Using
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        WriteExceptionErrorToFile("Main Page.xaml", "Window_Loaded()", ex.ToString())
        MsgBox("Please make sure that your database server is ONLINE.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

Next, when the window with the combobox loaded, I bind the datatable to the combobox such as

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Product_Combobox.ItemsSource = Nothing
    Product_Combobox.ItemsSource = productDT.DefaultView
    Product_Combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Product" 'This is the table's column name
    Product_Combobox.SelectedValuePath = "ID" 'This one as well. (For ID)
End Sub
```

Every thing is working here. So whenever I select an item from the combobox, a messagebox will show up like this
[image: This is when I selected the product 8]

So here is where the problem start. Whenever I add a new product such as below,
[image]
And click on the newly added product, the data seems missing? But the combobox still shows the new product text. The messagebox that was suppose to show what ID is selected is not even poping out. **The messagebox shows all the other product but not the newly product added**.
[image]

I apologize for the long question as I am trying my best to explain it properly.
Here is the code behind for the combobox

```
Private Sub Product_Combobox_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Product_Combobox.DropDownClosed
    If Product_Combobox.Text.Trim().Length() < 1 Or Product_Combobox.SelectedValue < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    whichID = New Integer
    whichID = Integer.Parse(Product_Combobox.SelectedValue)
    MsgBox(whichID.ToString())
    Try

        For Each checkRow As DataRow In productDT.Rows()
            If Not IsDBNull(checkRow("ID")) Then
                If checkRow("ID") = whichID Then
                    Amend_Customer_Price_Input.Text = checkRow("Customer Price")
                    Amend_Agent_Price_Input.Text = checkRow("Agent Price")
                    Amend_Unit_Price_Input.Text = checkRow("Unit Price")
                    Amend_Quantity_Input.Text = checkRow("Quantity")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        WriteExceptionErrorToFile("Product Page.xaml", "Product_Combobox_DropDownClosed()", ex.ToString())
        MsgBox("Error Code : " + ex.Number().ToString() + " - " + ex.Message + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "An error log file, AMErrLog has been generated on your desktop. Please forward it to : joshlcs93@gmail.com", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Product_Changes_Input.Text = Product_Combobox.Text.Trim()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for the add new product.

```
Private Sub New_Product_Confirm_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles New_Product_Confirm_Btn.Click
    Dim result As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Confirm?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        If Product_Name_Input.Text.Trim().Length() < 1 Then
            MsgBox("Product Name is empty!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        Dim newProduct = productDT.NewRow()
        newProduct.Item("Product") = Product_Name_Input.Text.Trim()
        newProduct.Item("Customer Price") = Decimal.Parse(Customer_Price_Input.Text.Trim())
        newProduct.Item("Agent Price") = Decimal.Parse(Agent_Price_Input.Text.Trim())
        newProduct.Item("Unit Price") = Decimal.Parse(Unit_Price_Input.Text.Trim())
        newProduct.Item("Quantity") = Integer.Parse(Quantity_Input.Text.Trim())
        productDT.Rows.Add(newProduct)

        productDA.Update(productDT)
        MsgBox("Successfully added.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Product_Combobox.SelectedIndex = -1
        Product_Changes_Input.Clear()
        Amend_Customer_Price_Input.Text = "0.00"
        Amend_Agent_Price_Input.Text = "0.00"
        Amend_Unit_Price_Input.Text = "0.00"
        Amend_Quantity_Input.Text = "0"
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        WriteExceptionErrorToFile("Product Page.xaml", "New_Product_Confirm_Btn_Click()", ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the event handler for the Confirm button, where I guess that you add the item, implemented?

Comment: @mm8 Updated my question with the add new product code as well.

Comment: You should set the Id of the newly added product: newProduct.Item("Id") = 100.

Comment: @mm8 But in the database, the ID is set to auto increment already

Answer (score 0):

Product_Combobox.SelectedValue would be < 1 if it is a new record as a new record would assigned an ID of zero until saved to the database, would this be correct? If so, this piece of code would be hit.

```
If Product_Combobox.Text.Trim().Length() < 1 Or Product_Combobox.SelectedValue < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: With some googling, I know the cause of it. But how do I fix it?

Comment: Instead of using SelectedValue, use SelectedItem and cast it to datarow then you can get all the properties of the selected Item. Something like IF Product_Combobox.SelectedItem ISNOT NULL Then dim row as DataRow = DirectCast(Product_Combobox.SelectedItem, DataRow)